# How can I implement inheritance with EF database-first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have this simple class:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Movie] (
  [MovieId] INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Title]   NVARCHAR (200)  NULL,
[Genre]   NVARCHAR (200)  NULL,
[Date]    DATE            NULL,
[Price]   DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Movies] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MovieId] ASC)
);
```

Now I want to implement a `SpecialMovie`... that has one additional property called `Special`.

I am working with a database-first approach.

I have tried to find some tutorials but nothing was really helpful.

I have a SQL Server 2008 book and it says nothing about inheritance...  isn't inheritance an important thing in SQL ? Its kind of strange that it has nothing on inheritance....

Comment: No, relational theory and relational databases don't have a concept of *inheritance* - they just store rows and columns ...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Implementing inheritance in EF is exactly the same as normal class inheritance, so in this case :

```
public class Movie
{
public int MovieID {get; set;}
//.....
}

public class SpecialMovie : Movie
{
public int SpecialMovieID {get; set;}
//.....

}

 public class MovieContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<SpecialMovie> SpecialMovies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies{ get; set; }
    }
```

Note that there isn't really a corresponding inheritance structure in a relational database such as SQL Server. Thus EF will implement inheritance in several ways Table per Hierarchy is probably the most performant but it will denormalize the data so that the data for both the SpecialMovie and Movie classes reside in the same table and EF adds a descriminator field to distinguish between the two classes. EF also offers Table-per-type and Table per Concrete Type. There is a good description of all three here http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx .

Comment: But I am not using Code-First. I am using DataBase First...So I cant have code like you did because i cant map the Model to the Database.... My DataBase is generating POCO classes not the oposite....

Comment: It will be much trickier using DB first, if you are generating your POCOs from your db I would suggest modifying the POCOs (ie adding the inherited classes) and then recreating the database using code first. DB first does not offer the same degree of fine tuning especially in inheritance structures as code first.

Comment: that is realy bad because I had problems with Foreign Keys with Code FIrst

Comment: -1, doesn't come close to the answer. Great explanation if it was about code first, useless when it's about DB first.